# AEM: datepicker with timezone selector in a coral3 dialog

Tags: datepicker, timezone, aem

Is there any ready solution I could use to ask the user for a date + time + timezone in an AEM edit dialog? The [Coral3 datepicker](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/coral-ui/coralui3/Coral.Datepicker.html) doesn't seem to support editing the timezone. I could provide an additional timezone select and have e.g. the datepicker save the date and time ignoring the browsers timezone with `valueFormat="YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:00.000[Z]"` , but that would mean I'd save the timezone and the date+time into two separate fields. Ideally I would have them joined into one. Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: you can use @TypeHint , see the the details here : https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html

Comment: @Pakira Sorry, I don't understand this: what has TypeHint to do with the timezone?